# Different values being assigned from same source. Strange

Tags: c++, ros

I am doing c++ coding for ROS. I wrote this code.

```
float32[] array1
float32[] array2
int32[] obs_check
```

[std_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs)

This is how StoM.msg file looks like. please note that this syntax is the ROS  syntax and we HAVE to assign either as float64 or float 32. Can we also do this in c+++ code ? like std::vector array_x;

This is the cpp file.

```
std::vector<float> array_x;
std::vector<float> array_y;
std::vector<int> obs_check1;
std::vector<float> nobs_x;
std::vector<float> nobs_y;
std::vector<float> d_ep_goal;

void SensortoMPNCallback(assign2::StoM obj)
{   
    if (obj.array1.size() != 0)
    {
        array_x.clear();
        array_y.clear();
        nobs_x.clear();
        nobs_y.clear();

        flag = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.array1.size(); i++)
        {
            obs_check1.push_back(obj.obs_check[i]);
            if (obj.obs_check[i] == 0)
            {
                ROS_INFO("Start of if");
                nobs_x.push_back(obj.array1[i]);
                nobs_y.push_back(obj.array2[i]);
                array_x.push_back(obj.array1[i]);
                array_y.push_back(obj.array2[i]);
            }
            else if (obj.obs_check[i] == 1)
            {   ROS_INFO("Start of else if");
                array_x.push_back(obj.array1[i]);
                array_y.push_back(obj.array2[i]);
            }
            ROS_INFO("Got x,y [%f],[%f]", obj.array1[i],obj.array2[i]);
            ROS_INFO("My x,y [%f],[%f]", array_x[i],array_y[i]);
            ROS_INFO("No obs_x,No obs_y [%f],[%f]", nobs_x[i],nobs_y[i]);
            ROS_INFO("status got [%d]", obj.obs_check[i]);
            ROS_INFO("status my [%d]", obs_check1[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

the output is below. You can clearly see that nobs_x and nobs_y is behaving weird. i dont understand why. in theory nobs_x should exactly behave like array_ except for when obj.obs_check == 1. Please explain why this is happening. what am UI missing as because of this miss, my program is a mess!!

```
[ INFO] [1393279223.062336300, 1056.296000000]: Got x,y [4.942642],[2.718085]
[ INFO] [1393279223.062651928, 1056.297000000]: My x,y [4.942642],[2.718085]
[ INFO] [1393279223.062931563, 1056.297000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.076604],[2.735721]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063120705, 1056.297000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063418319, 1056.298000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063489536, 1056.298000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.063548878, 1056.298000000]: Got x,y [4.950000],[2.713398]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063604675, 1056.298000000]: My x,y [4.950000],[2.713398]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063659180, 1056.298000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.081915],[2.742642]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063712605, 1056.298000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063766041, 1056.298000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063817998, 1056.298000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.063871795, 1056.298000000]: Got x,y [4.957738],[2.709369]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063926402, 1056.298000000]: My x,y [4.957738],[2.709369]
[ INFO] [1393279223.063982658, 1056.298000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.086603],[2.750000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064116523, 1056.299000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064166647, 1056.299000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064217780, 1056.299000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.064270886, 1056.299000000]: Got x,y [4.965798],[2.706031]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064328299, 1056.299000000]: My x,y [4.965798],[2.706031]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064381303, 1056.299000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.090631],[2.757738]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064439096, 1056.299000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064493752, 1056.299000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064541418, 1056.299000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.064592527, 1056.299000000]: Got x,y [4.974118],[2.703407]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064711455, 1056.299000000]: My x,y [4.974118],[2.703407]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064843991, 1056.299000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.093969],[2.765798]
[ INFO] [1393279223.064972151, 1056.299000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066053798, 1056.301000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066209830, 1056.301000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.066351915, 1056.301000000]: Got x,y [4.982635],[2.701519]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066400360, 1056.301000000]: My x,y [4.982635],[2.701519]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066490090, 1056.301000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.096592],[2.774118]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066577548, 1056.301000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066668389, 1056.301000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066755107, 1056.301000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.066841109, 1056.301000000]: Got x,y [4.991284],[2.700381]
[ INFO] [1393279223.066929419, 1056.301000000]: My x,y [4.991284],[2.700381]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067017180, 1056.301000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.098481],[2.782635]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067101128, 1056.301000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067184692, 1056.301000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067275368, 1056.301000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.067367026, 1056.301000000]: Got x,y [5.000000],[2.700000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067458201, 1056.301000000]: My x,y [5.000000],[2.700000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067545444, 1056.301000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [5.099619],[2.791284]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067629429, 1056.301000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067717692, 1056.301000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.067806051, 1056.301000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.067922643, 1056.302000000]: Got x,y [5.008716],[2.700381]
[ INFO] [1393279223.068055929, 1056.302000000]: My x,y [5.008716],[2.700381]
[ INFO] [1393279223.068204288, 1056.302000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.068406429, 1056.303000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.068553781, 1056.303000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.068703491, 1056.303000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.068853236, 1056.303000000]: Got x,y [5.017365],[2.701519]
[ INFO] [1393279223.069120890, 1056.304000000]: My x,y [5.017365],[2.701519]
[ INFO] [1393279223.069270681, 1056.304000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.069413183, 1056.304000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.069559232, 1056.304000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.069649302, 1056.304000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.069742869, 1056.304000000]: Got x,y [5.025882],[2.703407]
[ INFO] [1393279223.069837317, 1056.304000000]: My x,y [5.025882],[2.703407]
[ INFO] [1393279223.069981090, 1056.304000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000166],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.070146919, 1056.304000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.070335272, 1056.304000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.070406590, 1056.304000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.070547986, 1056.304000000]: Got x,y [5.034202],[2.706031]
[ INFO] [1393279223.070689189, 1056.305000000]: My x,y [5.034202],[2.706031]
[ INFO] [1393279223.070886457, 1056.305000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.070947098, 1056.305000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.071000829, 1056.305000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.071088936, 1056.305000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.071312900, 1056.305000000]: Got x,y [5.042262],[2.709369]
[ INFO] [1393279223.071371639, 1056.305000000]: My x,y [5.042262],[2.709369]
[ INFO] [1393279223.071520212, 1056.306000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[49652160681978098666684022784.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.071704500, 1056.306000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.071765282, 1056.306000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.071854062, 1056.306000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.072054525, 1056.306000000]: Got x,y [5.050000],[2.713398]
[ INFO] [1393279223.072117290, 1056.306000000]: My x,y [5.050000],[2.713398]
[ INFO] [1393279223.072211950, 1056.306000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[18128475639337701580720918478454784.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.072405258, 1056.306000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.072512798, 1056.307000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.072601386, 1056.307000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.073605977, 1056.308000000]: Got x,y [5.057358],[2.718085]
[ INFO] [1393279223.073798499, 1056.308000000]: My x,y [5.057358],[2.718085]
[ INFO] [1393279223.073861531, 1056.308000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.073948135, 1056.308000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.074145078, 1056.308000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.074274259, 1056.308000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.074369951, 1056.308000000]: Got x,y [5.064279],[2.723396]
[ INFO] [1393279223.074644050, 1056.308000000]: My x,y [5.064279],[2.723396]
[ INFO] [1393279223.074750515, 1056.308000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[17537701944724815872.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.074845207, 1056.308000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.074933693, 1056.308000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.075017897, 1056.308000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.075109592, 1056.308000000]: Got x,y [5.070711],[2.729289]
[ INFO] [1393279223.075317620, 1056.308000000]: My x,y [5.070711],[2.729289]
[ INFO] [1393279223.075409573, 1056.308000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.075494045, 1056.308000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.075694606, 1056.308000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.075823677, 1056.310000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.075872092, 1056.310000000]: Got x,y [5.076604],[2.735721]
[ INFO] [1393279223.075960848, 1056.310000000]: My x,y [5.076604],[2.735721]
[ INFO] [1393279223.076172643, 1056.310000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.076260578, 1056.310000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.076345102, 1056.311000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.077163899, 1056.311000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.077264851, 1056.311000000]: Got x,y [5.081915],[2.742642]
[ INFO] [1393279223.077476565, 1056.312000000]: My x,y [5.081915],[2.742642]
[ INFO] [1393279223.077595873, 1056.312000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[793481257882222592.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.077658217, 1056.312000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.077740911, 1056.312000000]: status my [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.077892263, 1056.312000000]: Start of if
[ INFO] [1393279223.077983340, 1056.312000000]: Got x,y [5.086603],[2.750000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.078161173, 1056.312000000]: My x,y [5.086603],[2.750000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.078224825, 1056.312000000]: No obs_x,No obs_y [0.000000],[0.000000]
[ INFO] [1393279223.078309932, 1056.312000000]: status got [0]
[ INFO] [1393279223.078410652, 1056.312000000]: status my [0]
```

Comment: post the struct/class that obj is a part of. It may have to do with some kind of implicit type conversion.

Comment: I have custom StoM.msg file ( as in ROS) it has the  data tyoes float64[] array1
float64[] array2
int64[] obs_check

Comment: As to your program being a "mess" (your words, not mine), you can clean it up by not using this awful "parallel array" approach.  Instead create a struct that has two float members and have an array of those instead of two disjoint arrays.

Comment: that's your problem then, why are you converting a 64 bit float to a 32 bit float? Keep your data types the same, especially when you are dealing with something like floating point numbers.

Comment: My be that will resolve. Bit I am also interested to know why array_x and nobs_x is behaving differently for the same index?

Comment: Where do you check if obj.obs_check is not empty? 
`obs_check1.push_back(obj.obs_check[i]`

Comment: In addition, your loop is dependent on the size of array1, but array2 is being accessed `as if` it is the same size as array1 in the loop. It would be much simpler if you just created a single struct instead of these "loose" arrays you have. Less chance of surprises.  Right now, we have no idea if array1 and array2 are the same size when you call this function.

Comment: @RedAlert Actually this didnt solve the problem.

Comment: @MT what does your code look like now?

Comment: @Paul, obj.obs_check is just the status of a currrnt x y point. it can be either 1 or 0 and same size as obj.array1 and obj.array2. I have a check in the other file from which all the x y points and the status are coming,

Comment: i changed my StoM.msg files to float32[] array1 float32[] array2 int32[] obs_check

Comment: change the types so they are **exactly the same**. Just use `float` for everything. Or `float32` for everything. Don't do *any* implicit type conversion. Also, edit your post to include your current code, and the class definition for obj.

Comment: oh, I guess it is just an out of bounds error. Your output is missing a line at the top, `Start of else if` I'm guessing? Use nobs_x.at(i) instead of nobs_x[i] to use the vector's built in bounds detection.

Comment: Well actually it will go in else if if it obj.obs_check == 1. And in the output I get some of these values. but coulndnt copy. Any ways thanks forr the time. i am really sleepy now. Will try sort out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding items to `nobs_x` and `nobs_y` inside of if statement, so it is probable that when you are accessing `nobs_x[i]` `i` is bigger than `nobs_x.size()`.